# SwiftUI Text Field Integer/Decimal Problem

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to suss out a problem I'm having. Basically, I have a text field for medical lab values, and I want it to display a symbol when out of range (out of normal medical limits) and another symbol when within normal range. These values are then used in formulae in another view in the app.

This is now my second post on this platform, so please forgive any posting faux pas, I'm trying to adhere to the rules as best as possible re: minimum reproducible and making sure my code is formatted properly in the posting. Here's what I have so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct EntryMRE: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
@State private var showingResults: Int? = 1

@FocusState private var isTextFieldFocused: Bool
@State var isDone = false

@State var isSaving = false //used to periodically save data
@State var saveInterval: Int = 5 //after how many seconds the data is automatically saved

//DataPoints Chemistry
@State var potassium = ""


var body: some View {
    List {
        Section(header: Text(" Chemistry")) {
            Group {
                HStack {
                    Text("K")
                    + Text("+")
                        .font(.system(size: 15.0))
                        .baselineOffset(4.0)
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("mEq/L", text: $potassium)
                        .focused($isTextFieldFocused)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
                        .modifier(TextFieldClearButton(text: $potassium))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    if potassium != "" && Int(potassium) != nil {
                        if Int(potassium)! >= Int(Double(Int(3.5))) && Int(potassium)! <= Int(Double(4.5)) {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen))
                        }
                        else {
                            Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemRed))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried making it `>= Double(3.5)` which then pops the same error and says it should be `Int(Double(3.5))` which does allow the code to build, but doesn't actually display the symbol when in range with a decimal ([ExhibitA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqCXe.png)), only with a whole integer. ([ExhibitB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBhwN.png))

I've added some pictures that'll hopefully help show what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a few issues with the rest of your code that you didn't post that I can tell from what you did post. When posting a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the person looking at your code should be able to copy it and run it in Xcode. That is what you are missing. Please note, `TextFields` have the ability to handle `Doubles` now. You don't have to convert it from a string to a number. If you put together a MRE, you will get a lot more help than you will with what you posted.

Comment: Edited original to reflect MRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fails because you are converting a Double to an Int and vice versa and casting your `String` to an `Int` instead of a `Double`. You are loosing your digits when you do this.

Try:

```
if let numberValue = Double(potassium) { // Cast String to Double
                    
  if (3.5...4.5) ~= numberValue { //Check if casted value is in customRange
         Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
             .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen))
                        }
  else {
         Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle.fill")
             .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemRed))
                    

        }
}
```